# Sidebar doesnt get updated?

Tags: php, theme-development, sidebar, css

I was trying to edit a theme by updating the style.css of it. But I also needed to add some manual html to the sidebar like ul li's . I maintained the order and updated the html od sidebar within the sidebar div, but I am not sure why wont the side bar get updated automatically. I am not sure if I also need to add this to the sidebar.php and where, why is the sidebar.php not catering to the whole of the sidebar div. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

for the widget html, don't forget to update/change the code of `register_sidebar()` in functions.php of your theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Answer (score -1):

**When ever your css isnt updated (and as a developer this happens!) you must have...**

1. not updated the right css class  OR
2. Havent uploaded the CSS / the right Css file to you server OR
3. have a different CSS rule over-writing it (checked with firebug?)
4. have a cache defined in your website... try clearing your browser
   (use ctrl + shift + delete -> delete all -> then refresh...)
5. You are trying to edit from within wordpress editor but
   have no file writing permission.. try downloading the file using
   an FTP software and check if the changes occuer.

**If you know how to handle your css / Html its nothing wordpress related but must likely 
one of the issuses show up in the list...**

Hope this helps.
best of luck, Sagive.

Comment: He asked for **HTML**.

Comment: "I was trying to edit a theme by updating the style.css" ... check hes message... also i have answered as to why the HTML might not show after update.. trying to help..

Comment: He is asking why the sidebar doesn’t update. That’s not the same file as the `style.css` …

Comment: i see.. i gave a reason why this might happen in point 4 & 5... if he is editing the sidebar.php he should see some changes and still doesent. i guess my next aproach was to ask him to paste he's revised sidebar.php... i shouldnt be afraid to try to help.. spending time here. the whole happy trigger finger on the minus is (in my humble opion is uncalled for).

Comment: Please don’t take votes personally. They are just a way to sort answers. I’m happy when you try to help. :) Just don’t do it for reputation only.

Comment: i dont care about points & dont take it personally.. i just think its uncalled for - you know, even if i am wrong... so what? trying to help. its not like i am spamming or anything. Anyhow what would the points give me? just here to learn and help. i love the community so i guess your doing whats right :) - thanks for the input